# Elasticsearch bucket aggregation returning wrong doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch bucket aggregation. I have a set of documents with each document having a category field which is an array. I need to get the count of each category along with the search results. But currently, I am getting the wrong doc_count.

This is my aggregation query

```
{

"aggs" : {
    "category" : {
        "terms" : { 
            "field" : "category.keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Below is the result I am getting with the wrong doc_count.

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 112,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "ljrbn3ABGDJu_xG-W2Mm",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "testing code.",
                "location_en": "Europe",
                "location_fr": "Europe-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:17",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:17",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "europe",
                    "researcher",
                    "law"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "lzrbn3ABGDJu_xG-W2PX",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Test",
                "slug": "Test",
                "location_en": "Asia",
                "location_fr": "Asia-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "uppsala-university",
                    "asia",
                    "PhD",
                    "history"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "mDrbn3ABGDJu_xG-W2Pl",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Test",
                "slug": "Test",
                "location_en": "Europe",
                "location_fr": "Europe-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "europe",
                    "researcher",
                    "law"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "mTrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XGOO",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Test",
                "slug": "Test",
                "location_en": "Asia",
                "location_fr": "Asia-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "asia",
                    "PhD",
                    "history"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "mjrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XGOb",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "testing world",
                "location_en": "Europe",
                "location_fr": "Europe-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "europe",
                    "researcher",
                    "law"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "mzrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XWNG",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "hello",
                "slug": "Helloo",
                "short_description_en": "Helloo",
                "location_en": "Asia",
                "location_fr": "Asia-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "asia",
                    "PhD",
                    "history"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "nDrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XWNU",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Hello",
                "slug": "helloo",
                "short_description_en": "hello worldf",
                "location_en": "Europe",
                "location_fr": "Europe-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "europe",
                    "researcher",
                    "law"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "nTrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XmMF",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Test",
                "slug": "test",
                "short_description_en": "Test",
                "location_en": "Asia",
                "location_fr": "Asia-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "asia",
                    "PhD",
                    "history"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "njrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XmMS",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Test",
                "slug": "test",
                "short_description_en": "Test",
                "location_en": "Europe",
                "location_fr": "Europe-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "europe",
                    "researcher",
                    "law"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "pages",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "nzrbn3ABGDJu_xG-XmPZ",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "title": "Researcher position in accelerator mass spectrometry (AMS)",
                "slug": "researcher-position-in-accelerator-mass-spectrometry-ams",
                "short_description_en": "Uppsala University is a comprehensive research-intensive university with a strong international standing. Our mission is to pursue top-quality research and education and to interact constructively with society. Our most important assets are all the individuals whose curiosity and...",
                "location_en": "Asia",
                "location_fr": "Asia-Fr",
                "start_date": "2020-03-03 10:05:18",
                "end_date": "2020-03-13 10:05:18",
                "category": [
                    "job",
                    "university",
                    "asia",
                    "PhD",
                    "history"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"aggregations": {
    "category": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "job",
                "doc_count": 112
            },
            {
                "key": "university",
                "doc_count": 112
            },
            {
                "key": "PhD",
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": "asia",
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": "europe",
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": "history",
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": "law",
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": "researcher",
                "doc_count": 56
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting unique (doc) counts out of arrays is known to cause headaches. Try using a scripted metric aggregation which

1. iterates through all your docs where it finds the category field
2. iterates through all the individual categories
3. and finally saves them in a hash map

which I think corresponds to the occurrence counts that you're after.

```
GET pages/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "scripted_non_uniques": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.map = [:];",
        "map_script": """
              if (doc.containsKey('category')) {
                for (def val : doc['category.keyword']) {
                  if (state.map.containsKey(val)) {
                    // increment if existing
                    state.map[val] += 1;
                  } else {
                    // initialize to increment later
                    state.map[val] = 1;
                  }
                }
              }
        """,
        "combine_script": "              return state",
        "reduce_script": "              return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields (based on the 10 hits from your example) the following:

```
{
  "took" : 17,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "scripted_non_uniques" : {
      "value" : [
        {
          "map" : {
            "law" : 5,
            "researcher" : 5,
            "university" : 9,
            "asia" : 5,
            "uppsala-university" : 1,
            "history" : 5,
            "job" : 10,
            "europe" : 5,
            "PhD" : 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this script would count duplicate categories in one `category` array multiple times so you should think about this edge case too.

You can debug the script code by calling `Debug.explain(val)` when you're, for example, in the for-loop. You can read up more on the scripting contexts [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-metric-agg-map-context.html).

Comment: I am getting the doc_counts in multiple buckets. Is there a way to get those in a single bucket

Comment: "value" => array:5 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "map" => array:10 [▼
            386 => 25
            
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:1 [▼
          "map" => array:10 [▼
            386 => 26
            
          ]
        ]
        2 => array:1 [▼
          "map" => array:10 [▼
            386 => 16
            
          ]
        ]
        3 => array:1 [▼
          "map" => array:10 [▼
            386 => 16
           
          ]
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          "map" => array:10 [▼
            386 => 17
          ]]